# findDOMNode warnings with CSSTransition components

Tags: reactjs, react-component, deprecation-warning, react-ref, strict-mode

"react": "^16.13.1"
"react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Hi, everyone.

I faced with findDOMNode warning and can't find the right solution on the internet.

> index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode...

This example I copied from off docs [here](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) and on click of the button, the same error appears.

```
const Toolbar = (props) => {
    const [inProp, setInProp] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <CSSTransition in={inProp} timeout={200} classNames="my-node">
                <div>
                    {"I'll receive my-node-* classes"}
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setInProp(true)}>
                Click to Enter
            </button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

The solutions from the internet suggested trying createRef (I used usePef hook) but with Transitions, it didn't work.

It seems that React.StrictMode will throw a warning like this until the patch for this library will be merged, but still, I don't see the created [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues)

I will be grateful for any help or proposal of how to solve the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They fixed that bug from version [4.4.0](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/1fd4a65ac45edd2aea3dec18eeb8b9c07c7eb93f/CHANGELOG.md#features).

To fix that can pass `nodeRef` to `CSSTransition`

```
const Toolbar = (props) => {
    const [inProp, setInProp] = useState(false);
    const nodeRef = useRef(null)
    return (
        <div>
            <CSSTransition in={inProp} nodeRef={nodeRef} timeout={200} classNames="my-node">
                <div ref={nodeRef}>
                    {"I'll receive my-node-* classes"}
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setInProp(true)}>
                Click to Enter
            </button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

I hope that will be helpful.

Comment: You forgot to add ref={nodeRef} to the child component.

Comment: I think this snippet of code is incomplete, I tried it without success..
The right one is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187461/using-react-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode-is-thrown-as-a-warning-when

Comment: I get no more warning but transition is gone?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using class-based components, it's recommended to use `createRef` instead.

**Example:**

```
const nodeRef = React.createRef(null);
```

I was having the same issue, and also as @warkentien2 said, you also need to add the reference in the child component, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Would you have a code snippet for a class version? I have a parent class (app.js) that uses a shared modal dialog component (modalInfo.js). Both are class based components. Can't figure out where and how to implement the ref to avoid the findDOMNode warning - and what (and how) to wrap with the css transition!