# Using React, findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode is thrown as a warning when using react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm using the package react-transition-group, I have tried using the nodeRef props on the CSSTransition component, and added a  wrapper on my component but I still get the warning regarding findDOMNode.

Here's the code:

```
 <CSSTransition
        key={entry.id}
        timeout={500}
        classNames="timesheet-entry"
      >
          <TimesheetEntry
            taskOptions={taskOptions || []}
            deleteHandler={(event) => {
              deleteHandler(event, entry.id.toString());
            }}
            data={entry}
            dateChangeHandler={(date: Date) =>
              dateChangeHandler(date, entry.id)
            }
            hoursChangeHandler={(event) => hoursChangeHandler(event, entry.id)}
            taskCodeChangeHandler={(event, value) =>
              taskCodeChangeHandler(event, value, entry.id)
            }
          />
      </CSSTransition>
```

Code for the TimesheetEntry component:

```
function TimesheetEntry(props: TimesheetEntryProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          label="Date"
          style={{ marginRight: '15px', height: '20px', marginTop: '-2px' }}
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          value={props.data.date}
          onChange={props.dateChangeHandler}
          size="small"
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

      <Autocomplete
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 300,
          display: 'inline-block',
          marginRight: '15px',
        }}
        options={props.taskOptions}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
          return option.id === value.id && option.name === value.name;
        }}
        onChange={props.taskCodeChangeHandler}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Task" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />

      <TextField
        size="small"
        style={{ marginRight: '15px', height: '20px' }}
        label="Hours"
        type="number"
        inputProps={{ min: 0.5, step: 0.5 }}
        onChange={props.hoursChangeHandler}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
      />

      <Button
        style={{ marginRight: '15px' }}
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        size="small"
        startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
        onClick={props.deleteHandler}
      >
        Delete
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TimesheetEntry;
```

I've also made a somewhat similar code setup in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-minsky-ong2j?file=/src/containers/Timesheet/Timesheet.tsx)

I've tried adding nodeRef and a ref reference through a div wrapper on my TimesheetEntry component but that seems to make the animation behave improperly(adding new entries works properly but when I try to delete the entry, the animation doesn't seem to work anymore). I'm also looking for a way without creating a div wrapper on the TimesheetEntry component.

Comment: your timesheet component returns multiple elements, so I'm not sure you will be able to achieve that without wrapping with a div. in this changelog it mentions you should use the noderef https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/1fd4a65ac45edd2aea3dec18eeb8b9c07c7eb93f/CHANGELOG.md#features

Comment: @erich I've already tried that prior to asking actually as I've mentioned in my post, the thing is when I tried it the warning no longer shows but the animation when a TimesheetEntry is deleted no longer works properly, also what happen is that the last item always get deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are actually two distinct `findDOMNode` warnings in your CodeSandbox demo:

1. When you first add or remove an entry, which originates from the direct usage of `react-transition-group` for `TimesheetEntry`.
2. When you save your timesheet, which originates from the *indirect* usage of `react-transition-group` through Material UI's `Snackbar` component.

Unfortunately, you have no control over the latter, so let's fix the former; you're managing a list of transitioning `TimesheetEntry` components, but to correctly implement `nodeRef`, each element needs a distinct ref object, and because you cannot call React hooks within a loop (see [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)), you have to create a separate component:

```js
const EntryContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const nodeRef = React.useRef(null);
  return (
    <CSSTransition
      nodeRef={nodeRef}
      timeout={500}
      classNames="timesheet-entry"
      {...props}
    >
      <div ref={nodeRef}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
};
```

which you will wrap around `TimesheetEntry`:

```
const controls: JSX.Element[] = entries.map((entry: entry, index: number) => {
  return (
    <EntryContainer key={entry.id}>
      <TimesheetEntry
        deleteHandler={event => {
          deleteHandler(event, entry.id.toString());
        }}
        data={entry}
        dateChangeHandler={(date: Date) => dateChangeHandler(date, entry.id)}
        hoursChangeHandler={event => hoursChangeHandler(event, entry.id)}
        taskCodeChangeHandler={(event, value) =>
          taskCodeChangeHandler(event, value, entry.id)
        }
      />
    </EntryContainer>
  );
});
```

You said that you tried something like this already, but my suspicions are that you forgot to forward `EntryContainer`'s props to `CSSTransition`, which is the crucial step because those are being passed down by `TransitionGroup`.

Comment: that's where I got stuck because I can't use hooks(useRef) on a loop, I just wasn't able to think of creating  an EntryContainer to circumvent that. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like I'm having a similar issue here...but I checked that I was passing in my props and all is well.  Exit transitions work, but not enter.  Can someone spot the bug in this wrapper component?  (TS) https://gist.github.com/stevecastaneda/899e83d47fa27397c447e2e6ae3d7771

Comment: I don't know whether it's a similar issue, but I recommend posting a new question explaining what is the purpose of this wrapper and why you're using Transition instead of CSSTransition, which contains a crucial reflow hack needed for CSS transitions to work as expected, [as explained in the docs](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition).

Comment: @silvenon I have one unrelated question. What would be the solution for this if I want to have only <CSSTransition ...>{children}</CSSTransition> without the wrapping <div>. I got stuck at this because it won't work without that ref of the wrapping <div> which I want to get rid off as it affects my layout a lot

Comment: @IceWhisper `nodeRef` **has** to refer to a DOM node that is wrapping your transitioning content. I would need to know more about your situation in order to find a solution for your specific case. Maybe best to ask another Stack Overflow question and ping me on Twitter. (@silvenon)

Comment: @silvenon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149840/csstransition-noderef-for-component-with-direct-children

Answer (score 1):

[Caleb Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8234457/caleb-taylor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70615130/3279029) solves the problem by forwarding the ref, and you can avoid using `// @ts-ignore` if you test the child element's validity before cloning it. For instance,

```
import { Children, cloneElement, isValidElement, useRef } from 'react';
import { CSSTransition as _CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import { CSSTransitionProps } from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition';

export const CSSTransition = ({ children, ...props }: CSSTransitionProps) => {
  const nodeRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <_CSSTransition {...props} nodeRef={nodeRef}>
      <>
        {Children.map(children, child =>
          isValidElement(child)
            ? cloneElement(child, { ref: nodeRef })
            : child
        )}
      </>
    </_CSSTransition>
  );
};
```

The idea came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486160/3279029) to an unrelated question.

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses the same strategy as @sivenon's answer, but it's annoying to write "useless" refs that takes up space in the Component where your Transition is used. So here's a wrapper that adds the refs for you without using hidden divs because extra markup will ruin styling.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { CSSTransition as _CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import { CSSTransitionProps } from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition';

const CSSTransition = (props: CSSTransitionProps) => {
  const nodeRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <_CSSTransition {...props} nodeRef={nodeRef}>
      <>
        {React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
          // @ts-ignore
          return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: nodeRef });
        })}
      </>
    </_CSSTransition>
  );
};

export default CSSTransition;
```