# CSSTransition nodeRef for component with direct children

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, reactcsstransitiongroup

I want to get rid of the warning on `StrictMode` for `findDOMNode` when using `react-transition-group` but I stumbled upon an issue.

My `<Slide>` component looks like this:

```
class Slide extends React.Component {
  nodeRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <CSSTransition
        in={this.props.in}
        timeout={ANIMATION_DURATION}
        mountOnEnter={true}
        unmountOnExit={true}
        classNames={{
          enter: "slideEnter",
          enterActive: "slideEnterActive",
          exit: "slideExit",
          exitActive: "slideExitActive"
        }}
        nodeRef={this.nodeRef}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  }
}
```

It receives a `Drawer` element as children, the `Drawer` component looks like this:

```
class Drawer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="drawer">
        <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>close me</button>{" "}
        <div>This is my drawer</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I cannot wrap the `children` element with a HTML tag (to attach a ref `<div ref={this.nodeRef}>{this.props.children}</div>` because it breaks the animation of the content. (I'm using this for children that are different drawers with position absolute)

I've also tried with `cloneElement` but it still doesn't work (with the code from below it behaves like this: 1. `in` no animation, 2. `out` no animation, 3. `in` animation works but I get the warning `findDOMNode` so it seems that nodeRef is sent as null, 4. `out` animation does not work.

```
const onlyChild = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
const childWithRef = React.cloneElement(onlyChild, {
  ref: this.nodeRef;
});
```

Is there any solution for this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Could you try setting `ref: this.nodeRef` instead? If that fixes it, I'll write an answer explaining it.

Comment: If I use it like that I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined
    at hasClass (hasClass.js?1d84:3)
    at addClass (addClass.js?0d03:3)
    at eval (CSSTransition.js?e9c9:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at addClass (CSSTransition.js?e9c9:12)
    at CSSTransition.addClass (CSSTransition.js?e9c9:237)
    at Object.CSSTransition._this.onEnter (CSSTransition.js?e9c9:117)
    at Transition.performEnter (Transition.js?9b73:262)
    at Transition.updateStatus (Transition.js?9b73:228)
    at Transition.componentDidUpdate`

Comment: I was able to do it in my example. Could you reproduce your problem in a CodeSandbox? Just a small version of the situation you're in.

Comment: the error appears when you click the button https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-fast-jvg83?file=/src/Slide.tsx

Comment: I applied some edits to your question to include relevant info (it's in review). I also suggest that you edit your question to say `ref: this.nodeRef`, just so my answer doesn't have to address two problems, only the core one.

Comment: Hey, not sure if you noticed, but I posted an answer a while ago which should solve the issue.

Comment: Hey. sorry, I was under the impression that I've sent a reply to you. Yep. The solution makes sense. Thanks! I just have to see how I can adapt it to my specific cases as I have a couple of intermediate react components in between. It's smth like <Slide><DrawerCycle></Slide> then DrawerCycle can render multiple types of drawers and inside each type I use the actual <Drawer> comp. So I have to propagate that `ref` prop through all the components until it gets to the one that uses a DOM element, but I don't like it that much :(

Comment: Yeah, sounds problematic, I hope you find an easier way than ref drilling  Let me know on Twitter if you need some more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `nodeRef` needs to point to a DOM Node, as the name suggests, in your case it points to an instance of the `Drawer` class. You have two options:

1. Pass the ref through another prop, e.g. `forwardedRef`, and in the `Drawer` class pass that prop to the root element:

```
React.cloneElement(onlyChild, {
  forwardedRef: this.nodeRef,
})
```

```
<div ref={this.props.forwardedRef} className="drawer">
```

2. Convert `Drawer` to a function component and use [`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref):

```
const Drawer = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="drawer">
      <button onClick={props.onClose}>close me</button>{" "}
      <div>This is my drawer</div>
    </div>
  );
});
```